# How can I access customized UITableViewCell from UITableView using indexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created custom `UiTableViewCell` with some `UIImageViews` and `UILabels`.
Now I have problem: when I scroll `tableView` I want to get this `cellForYoutube` in visiblePaths.

Thats how I trying to do this:

```
   - (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows
{
    if (videos.count > 0)
    {
        NSArray *visiblePaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
        {cellForYoutube *cell = (cellForYoutube *)[(UITableView *)self.view cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//There it show me erorr: -[UIView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
           if (!cell.thumb.image){
                NSLog(@"WAS NOTHING IN IMAGE");
               [self startIconDownload:cell withIndexPath:indexPath];}

        }
    }
}
```

How can fix it?

Comment: ((UITableView *)self.view )  cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` message to `self.view` which is apparently a `UIView` and not a `UITableView`. Instead send that message to `self.tableView` (the same object you called `-indexPathsForVisibleRows` on.

Casting `self.view` to a `UITableView *` tells the compiler to trust that that object will be of that type but does not make it so.